# How to measure response times of API calls?

Tags: spring, api

I have implemented an API in Spring Boot which does all the RESTful calls successfully.

As an extra credit part of the assignment, I am required to track response time of all the calls to the RESTful service and be able to visualise the data on a
line graph.

They suggested using grafana which I have downloaded.

I'm just not sure on how I would be able to track the response time of each call

Answer (score 4):

The response time can easily be tracked using the chrome debugger. 
[image]

If you want to compute the response time programmatically then it may be achieved by  using the
 `System.currentTimeMillis()` method.

The following pseudo snippet may be helpful.

`long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();`

`//your code to call the rest api`

`long responseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;`